# Decrypt, Encrypt

Tags: php

This is what I'm trying to do :

I have a CMS website, in my admin panel i can add some packages users can buy from my website. So in my Choose.php page, users can select which package the want to buy. And of course the price is set for each package not by them, but by me.

If they click on a package, the page sends the data to another page like this :

```
$form  = '<form action="/buy.php?'product_name='.$name.'&product_id='.$product_id.'&price='.$ammount.'" method="post" target="_parent" ><input type="submit"     style="background-image:url(images/p.png);height: 55px;width: 118px;" value=""/></form>';
```

So users only click on predefined packages. If a user is some how expert in PHP, or even in scripting, he can easily change the url like :

> product_name=MYPRODUCT&product_id=1&price=1000$

to something like this :

> product_name=MYPRODUCT&product_id=1&price=10$

this means, they can buy the same package for 10& instead of 1000$.

So i need to ecrypt this url which is gernerated for each package separately, to something like this :

```
$form  = '<form action="/buy.php?MVNnaPgxpQizqwv7YElroi5E" method="post" target="_parent" ><input type="submit"     style="background-image:url(images/p.png);height: 55px;width: 118px;" value=""/></form>';
```

then in my Buy.php page, this encrypted string, deycrypts.

But the problem is with the decryption part, because when I deycrypt it, it says it's an Array ( because i use $_GET to get the url ).

And when I use array deycription methods, i get an error in my first page, which it says the value i'm encrypting is a String not an Array. ( Remember : product_name=MYPRODUCT&product_id=1&price=1000$           which is a string. )

So how can i encrypt a string in one page, send it through url ( with $_POST ) then in the Buy.php page, use the $_GET and deycrypt it to arrays.

Sorry if it becomes a long post. And I need an encryption/decryption code.

Comment: Don't do that. Just fetch the price and product name from the project ID in `buy.php`. And it really doesn't take an expert to change the URL...

Comment: @Rajeev : i'm using post in my form.

Comment: @RajeevS, POST provides no extra security.

Comment: @ minitech : This would be good, if the packages where static. But this is a CMS panel, and i'm changing the prices and adding more packages daily.

Comment: I mean its better than GET allowing user to see the content in the url,isnt it?

Comment: If you can decrypt the url, so can any moderately tech savvy person. As suggested already, it's much better to not pass such information through $_GET or $_POST, but rather retrieve it directly from the database. Then there's no chance if it being tampered with.

Comment: @Rajeev S, it is only slightly better, because anyone with a browser console like FireBug can edit the contents of hidden fields and still change the data being sent. So no, the data isn't in the URL, but still subject to change by the end user.

Comment: @user1391170: Have you heard of databases? I'm sure that's where you're storing the prices already... (Also, when you put a space after the `@`, it doesn't actually notify me, FYI.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons I would advise you not to forward any sensitive data through GET/POST parameters!
Even if they are encrypted, there might be a way for attackers to encrypt it and bring a lot of damage to you.

You should store the price of the product in a database. When the user selects a product you forward to sth. like

$form  = '<form action="/buy.php?id=34">'

And in buy.php you then retrieve the price and additional informations from the database.

My advise is to read or at least have a look at [PHP Security Guide](http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/)

Comment: I think your advise is a good advise. I need to use MYSQL which i'm using currently for my website. tnx again. ;)